# Modifying a list outside of recursive function in Python

Tags: python, list, function, recursion, hyperlink

There is a multidimensional list with not clear structure:

```
a=[[['123', '456'], ['789', '1011']], [['1213', '1415']], [['1617', '1819']]]
```

And there is a recursive function, which operates the list:

```
def get_The_Group_And_Rewrite_It(workingList):
    if isinstance(workingList[0],str):
        doSomething(workingList)
    else:
        for i in workingList:
            get_The_Group_And_Rewrite_It(i)
```

Through time the `get_The_Group_And_Rewrite_It()` should get a list, for instance, `['123','456']`, and as soon as it get it, `doSomething` function should rewrite it with `['abc']` in entire list.

The same with other lists of `format[str,str,...]`. In the end I should get something like

```
a=[[['abc'], ['abc']], [['abc']], [['abc']]]
```

I see it would be easy in C++, using `*links`, but how to do that in Python?

Comment: Don't do regular assignments, because then you lose the original object. That's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this case, you can use slice assignment:

```
>>> a = [[['123', '456']]]
>>> x = a[0][0]
>>> x[:] = ['abc']
>>> a
[[['abc']]]
```

---

```
>>> def f(workingList):
...     if isinstance(workingList[0],str):
...         workingList[:] = ['abc']
...     else:
...         for i in workingList:
...             f(i)
...
>>> a=[[['123', '456'], ['789', '1011']], [['1213', '1415']], [['1617', '1819']]]
>>> f(a)
>>> a
[[['abc'], ['abc']], [['abc']], [['abc']]]
```